# Smoke detectors (wired/wireless) - how much is enough

Tags: wire, smoke-detectors

Our house is fairly new (2013 build year). We moved in 2016. On the second floor we have 3 wireless smoke detectors and 1 wired and on the first floor we have 1 wired smoke detector and 2 wireless. They are all positioned in about the same area. I am curious why do we have so many and can we get rid off wireless (it is time to replace them anyway)

I am trying to research everything. And so far I only found something about ADT alarm. We do have ADT installed.

**Update on position**. On the second floor all smoke detectors are located in the hallway (not in bedrooms). They all positioned on the area of roughly 1 m^2.
On the first floor all smoke detectors are in the hallway next to bathroom, laundry room, living room, bedroom and fairly far from kitchen. They are all positioned on the area of roughly 1 m^2.

**More update** I just carefully inspected the second floor and found out that there is smoke detector in each bedroom (total of 3), they are all wired. There is also extra wired smoke detector in hall way next to two bedrooms. Also one bedroom on the first floor has wired smoke detector. It seems like all other wireless smoke detectors are excessive.

Comment: I suspect the second floor has 3 bedrooms and there is one smoke detector per bedroom?

Comment: Perhaps a diagram showing the rooms and position of the smoke detectors? Rather difficult to provide any input on why you have that number without knowing the layout. Commonly they are trying to notice probable fire sources without being so close to the kitchen as to have nuisance trips, and protect bedrooms (typically in the hallways outside of them, if you smoke in bed, inside might also be good.)

Comment: Thank you for replies! I updated post with description of position.

Comment: Some of those "extra" ones might be carbon monoxide detectors.

Answer (score 2):

This might explain why you have many in the same area especially if in the sleeping area of the house.

https://www.nfpa.org › Public-Education › Staying-safe › Safety-equipment
Install smoke alarms inside each bedroom, outside each sleeping area and on every level of the home, including the basement. On levels without bedrooms, install alarms in the living room (or den or family room) or near the stairway to the upper level, or in both locations.

Some of the "extra" ones you think you have might be carbon monoxide detectors. I'd think twice about removing any safety devices.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I just updated post after your answer. It looks like we have plenty of wired smoke detectors. I am not sure if we need wireless at all.

Comment: Since your wired ones are evidently associated with a central alarm you don't pay for service on, have you verified that they actually work as expected?